# javascript button settings

Tags: javascript, html

I can try to make a few music buttons but I added new Audio and new audio.play for example audio.play2 but if I add this one, it doesn't work first.

What can I do?

```
<div class="song"><button onclick="play1()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-1x"> </i></button><button onclick="pause1()"><i class="fa fa-pause fa-1x"></i></button></i>song name</div>

<div class="müzik"><button onclick="play2()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-1x"></i></button><button onclick="pause2()"><i class="fa fa-pause fa-1x"></i></button></i>next song</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "file name/song name.mp3";
audio.loop = false;

function play1(){ 
  audio.play();
}
function pause1(){
  audio.pause();
}

audio= new Audio();
audio.src="file name/next song.mp3"
audio.loop=false;

function play2(){
    audio.play();
}
function pause2(){
    audio.pause2();
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `play2()` function in your code, so your `onclick` handler in the 2nd button does nothing

Comment: If you can provide an example in plnkr or something similar we can try to help. Also you have a few tags that don't appear to close anything: </i> and a method that doesn't appear to exist: audio.pause2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="song"><button onclick="play1()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-1x"> </i></button><button onclick="pause1()"><i class="fa fa-pause fa-1x"></i></button></i>song name</div>

<div class="müzik"><button onclick="play2()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-1x"></i></button><button onclick="pause2()"><i class="fa fa-pause fa-1x"></i></button></i>next song</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio1 = new Audio();
audio1.src = "file name/song name.mp3";
audio1.loop = false;

function play1(){ 
  audio1.play();
}
function pause1(){
  audio1.pause();
}

var audio2 = new Audio();
audio2.src="file name/next song.mp3"
audio2.loop=false;

function play2(){
    audio2.play();
}
function pause2(){
    audio2.pause2();
}
</script>
```

The issue is your redefining the variable and source for the variable `audio`. I'd recommend having a variable (like shown above) for every source.